# Loop asynchronous function inside two chain asynchronous function and inside another loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I have a 3 asynchronous functions wrap by a loop1, inside the first 2 asynchronous functions are chained after successfully executing each of the first 2 functions, the last async function is wrap with a another loop. This will be the problem, the loop will not wait for the 3rd async function to excute and return a value before looping again.

the ts code that will call the provider, this is the loop 1

```
for(var i=0; i<maxValue; i++){
    if(this.loanSteps.length > i){
       this.localdb.insertStepsToApply(this.loanSteps[i]);
      }
    }
```

the provider function code

```
  insertStepsToApply(stepsValue){
    return this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'govservices.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      return db.executeSql('INSERT INTO application_steps(steps_program_refer_id,steps) VALUES ('+this.governmentprogram_id+',"'+stepsValue+'")',[])
      .then(res=>{
        console.log('inserted steps');   
        return db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM application_steps ORDER by appsteps_id DESC LIMIT 1', [])
        .then(async res=>{
          if(res.rows.length > 0){
              this.applyStepsid = res.rows.item(0).appsteps_id;
              console.log('extracting app steps id ->'+this.applyStepsid);
              var steplength = stepsValue.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length; // new line
              var stepLengthblankspace = (stepsValue.match(/^[ \t]*$/gm) || []).length; // blank spaces
              var numberOfSentences = steplength - stepLengthblankspace;

              for(var ix=0; ix < numberOfSentences; ix++){
                await db.executeSql('INSERT INTO requirement_list(requirement_government_program_id, requirement_steps_id) VALUES ('+this.governmentprogram_id+','+this.applyStepsid+')',[])
                .then(res =>{
                  alert('successfully inserted to steps apply requiermeent box');
                    return res;
                  }).catch(e =>{
                    console.log(e.message); 
                  });
              }
          }
        }).catch(e => console.log(e.message));
      }).catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    }).catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  }
```

note that the inside loop will depend on how many sentence does the steps value has, this stepvalue is a textbox and has a paragraph
the expected output that I want is like this

```
inserted steps
extracting app steps id -> 3
successfully inserted to steps apply requirement box
successfully inserted to steps apply requirement box
successfully inserted to steps apply requirement box
inserted steps
extracting app steps id -> 4
successfully inserted to steps apply requirement box
successfully inserted to steps apply requirement box
```

but the actual is like this

```
inserted steps
extracting app steps id -> 3
inserted steps
extracting app steps id -> 4
successfully inserted to steps apply requirement box
successfully inserted to steps apply requirement box
successfully inserted to steps apply requirement box
successfully inserted to steps apply requirement box
successfully inserted to steps apply requirement box
```

I also putting promise outside the inner loop(loop2) but still the output is not correct, any idea on how to handle something like this?

Comment: Just my 2 cents; when your code starts becoming convoluted like this, it’s often better to chop it up into separate functions that can be tested individually.

Comment: @Kokodoko that will be better i think i`ll try it

Comment: Try not to mix `then` with `await` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just solve my problem as what @Kokodoko suggested, creating another function to something like this

```
    return db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM application_steps ORDER by appsteps_id DESC LIMIT 1', [])
    .then(async res=>{
      if(res.rows.length > 0){
          this.applyStepsid = res.rows.item(0).appsteps_id;
          console.log('extracting app steps id ->'+this.applyStepsid);
          var steplength = stepsValue.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length; // new line
          var stepLengthblankspace = (stepsValue.match(/^[ \t]*$/gm) || []).length; // blank spaces
          var numberOfSentences = steplength - stepLengthblankspace;
          console.log('total sentences '+numberOfSentences+' = '+steplength+' - '+stepLengthblankspace);
          for(var ix=0; ix < numberOfSentences; ix++){
            await this.insertIntoRequirementCheckbox();
          }
      }
    }).catch(e => console.log(e.message));

insertIntoRequirementCheckbox(){
return this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'govservices.db',
  location: 'default'
}).then((db: SQLiteObject) =>{
  return db.executeSql('INSERT INTO requirement_list(requirement_government_program_id, requirement_steps_id) VALUES ('+this.governmentprogram_id+','+this.applyStepsid+')',[])
  .then(res =>{
    console.log('requirement checkbox successfully inserted');
    }).catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  }).catch(e => console.log(e.message));
}
```